# Signal function in another thread to start working

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, signals

A `worker thread` is expected to check for a certain condition. When the condition is satisfied, it should `notify` another `function` in another thread, even the `main` thread, let's say, that it should now do something, and be prevented from continuing with its checks till the other function has completed its task.

With `Qt`, I'd have used a combination of `Signal-Slot` and `synchronization` techniques to achieve this, but I am not sure what would be the best way to do it in `C++`. I have looked at some of the newer sync mechanisms in C++, such as `std::condition_variable`, or `std::promise` and `std::future`, however, for these mechanisms, it seems as if something will "wait" or has to wait for the call to start working.

Is there a way for a routine to start executing only when it's needed, and not have to "wait" on the result of a promise or a condition_variable notify? I know that this essentially sounds like a `callback`, but I'd like to keep concerns separate. I also thought that, since REST is used heavily, the worker thread can simply send a `POST` to the concerned, listening server, which would then start the routine...but I'd prefer if there were a simpler way...

`Thread` is a `std::thread`.

Comment: _Is there a way for a routine to start executing only when it's needed, and not have to "wait" on the result of a promise or a condition_variable notify?_ What is the essential difference? I believe that Qt threads (with a run-time loop) don't do something different. As you mentioned Qt signals, a direct call means that the function is done in the same thread. For inter-thread communication, the run-time loop of `QEvent` is mandatory as it's involved in this. With `std::condition_variable`, you can build something similar but more lightweight suitable to your actual needs.

Comment: If you want to exchange certain states between threads, `std::atomic` might be a choice as well. But as soon as you're are polling for something I would prefer a `std::condition_variable::wait()` over a busy-loop. The former suspends the thread until condition is met, the latter makes the computer loud. ;-)

Comment: An [MCVE] would be appropriate. It seems you already had a solution in Qt. So, why don't you make your MCVE in Qt to illustrate your approach (you want to achieve without Qt)?

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your comment. I don't have an example in Qt, I just thought that's what I'd try to do in Qt. I understand your comments though, I'll look further into it, seems unless there's a direct callback, in some form or another, some waiting on a trigger is essential, whether implemented by you or the underlying framework.